# Identification of IC used on LCD control board - top markings [logo] SiW SW50008 ABGL0004F 1745

Tags: identification, lcd

[image: IC top markings]

I need help with identification of this IC. It is on an LCD control board.

Comment: You just deleted your previous question that was essentially identical to this one. Your previous question was closed. If you have more information, you should add it to the existing question rather than create a new one.

Comment: Link to old question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563138/find-this-part-datasheet

Comment: sung kim - Hi, Please read the comments above. Deleting and re-posting the same question, just because you didn't like the previous response, is *not acceptable* here. For example, it can waste the time of readers who didn't see the previous time you asked the question, and then they spend (waste!) their time giving the same reply as before, as they didn't know it had already been given.

Comment: Instead of asking for its datasheet (you can search Google as well as we can!) I'm converting this into an *IC identification* question. Those are on-topic here. Your original question text was also asking for the IC  "name" i.e. an identification request, and you have now received an answer which helps with that question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a product of Silicon Works: https://www.siliconworks.co.kr/en/web/main. Maybe you can contact the customer service.